# How to use Dapr to communicate in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dapr

I'm trying to learn Dapr and Docker Compose at the same time, though I am running into some problems. I have a very basic docker-compose.yaml, shown below

```
version:"3.7"
services:
    python-service:
        image: python-image
    java-service:
        image: java-image
```

My goal is to make these be able to communicate over Dapr (currently they are simple hello world programs, but I'm trying to get the connection working first.)

My goal architecture would be something like:

- [python-service][Dapr-sidecar]
- [java-service][Dapr-sidecar]

Having the services talk to the sidecar, and the sidecars talk to eachother over a network. I'm quite stumped on how to achieve this, and I can't seem to find any guides online to fit my exact case.

I tried to follow the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66402611/17494949, However it game me a bunch of errors, seemed to use some other system, and didn't explain how to run it. Any help would be appreciated.